# Comparisons of kernel distribution parameters

Tags: modeling, kernel-smoothing, histogram

I am carrying out modelling of a histogram, which doesn't appear to be Gaussian.  The kernel distribution in Matlab showed a reasonable fit.  If I were to compare the histograms across subjects, could I use the bandwidth parameter to do that?

Comment: Could you please clarify *how* you would use the bandwidth parameter to carry out a comparison of histograms?  Is this truly a parameter (in the sense you control it) or is it a value that your kernel density estimator has computed for you?

Comment: The bandwidth estimated by a kernel density estimator, e.g., the fitdist function in Matlab.

Comment: So, in what way do you conceive of using this estimated bandwidth to compare histograms?

Comment: For example, the estimated bandwidths obtained from one group: could these be used as a range to characterise the group?  For normal distributions, one would perhaps use mean and standard deviation.  I would like to know in the case of kernel distribution, would bandwidth be playing a similar role.

Comment: Have you noticed that the bandwidth tends to change with the amount of data?  Since the data count does not give you any information about the data distribution, it looks like the bandwidth alone would be useless for your purpose.  You might find it more constructive to ask *how* to compare two empirical distributions rather than asking whether some particular proposal makes sense.